# What does "POP" mean in the context of charity/forms/information?

Tags: meaning

What does "POP" mean below?

> このたびのスペシャルイベントでも、オーディエンスのみなさんがサポートしたくなるようなプロジェクトについて、会場でPOPなどで紹介し、ドネイション（基金）を募りたいと考えています。

Also:

> 団体名と簡単な概要入りの共通POPはこちらで作ります。

Also:

[This PDF](http://wakasinkojapuchi.web.fc2.com/img/kikaku.pdf) lists `共通POP一枚` as a required item.

Nothing on [ALC](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=POP) nor [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/POP).

Answer (score 6):

POP広告 means "Point of purchase advertising", and POP seems to have become a synonym for in-store advertisements like this one:

[image]

Thanks to Yuichiro Fujiwara for the tip!